# MVVM Catch Cut, Copy, and Paste Textbox Event

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, event-handling

I've looked all over for a good solution on this, but nothing is helping.What I need is listen for for cut, copy, and paste events and be able to manipulate the data in the clipboard.  I think one path could possibly be a dependency property, but how could I implement this on a textbox using User Control?  Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: You would replace the context menu, and intercept the keyboard commands. On Ctrl+C, do whatever you like. I'm not sure what you mean by "implement this on a text box using user control".

Comment: You need to explain more on this. This is too vague. Everyone who is attempting to answer is totally guessing what you need now.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I think you’re looking for **setting**/**getting** the text to/from the clip board.

You can use the `Clipboard.SetText(stringObj)` or `Clipboard.GetText()` for your requirement. It belongs to the System.Windows namespace.
You can read more it in in msdn - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms597043.aspx

If you want to copy text from a textbox to clipboard at any time,

```
 Clipboard.SetText(txtBoxName.Text);
```

Whenever you want to access data copied in clipboard

```
 Clipboard.GetText();
```